# Looping Through a list initialize in a class

Tags: python, list

I am trying to loop through a list declared in my class but on running my code i realise the list is not iterable and i don't know why any explanation is welcomed

```
class Wordplay:
    def __init__(self):
        self.words_list = []


    def words_with_length(self,length):
        for w in self.words_list:
            if len(w) == length:
                return w

    def start_with(self,s):
        for w in self.words_list:
            if w[:1] == s:
               return w

a = Wordplay()

a.words_list=["Marcus","Aurelius","Henry","tirla","samantha","pocahontas","sorry"]

print(a.start_with("s"))
```

Trying to print words starting with S will only give me samantha and then the program stops

Comment: Why are you slicing when checking whether first letter matches in start_with function? Isn't it more clear to use w[0]?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Beginner here so  learning everyday

Comment: No problem at all. It actually didn't matter whether you used w[:1] or w[0], it just helps readability.

Answer (score 1):

Because you return the value that achieves the if condition, you could maybe add the values that achieve the if condition in a list and return it

```
class Wordplay:
def __init__(self):
    self.words_list = []


def words_with_length(self,length):
    for w in self.words_list:
        if len(w) == length:
            return w

def start_with(self,s):
    wordsStartWith = []
    for w in self.words_list:
        if w[:1] == "s":
            wordsStartWith.append(w)
    return wordsStartWith
```

**EDIT:** Check the image here, make sure the indentation is right

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdnuE.png)

Comment: Did you run your solution?. I returns only samantha

Comment: yea did it returned both values in a list, maybe something wrong with the indentation on your side, check the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdnuE.png

Comment: It works!! I had capital S instead of s thank you

Comment: sure, you can always add .lower()>>> make it w[0].lower() =="s" to include both the upper and lower case from your list

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement stops the `for` loop you're using to access every element in the list, by returning first matching element. You might use the `print` function inside the `start_with` function itself instead of the returning the match, or you could just append every matching element to a list and then return the list itself. Your choice.

**EDITED FOR**:

Since you want to append to a list and return that, here is the code:

```
def start_with(self,s):
    finalList = []
    for w in self.words_list:
        if(w[0] == s):
            finalList.append(w)
    return finalList
```

Return value of this function will be a list filled with all words starting with s, or an empty one if no word starts with s.

Comment: Appending to a list still doesn't work i tried it out and printing only show samantha

Comment: Check the edit, and if the answer suits your needs, please accept it as default answer.

Comment: did you run your code ? the output is samantha and not the expected output samantha & sorry I did try this method just as suggested below and the output is the same

Comment: I did run my code, and it returns a list with samantha and sorry.

Comment: Strange im using pycharm the out put is only samantha

Comment: It works!! I had capital S instead of s thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)
function combined with the [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method.

Comment: Can you actually write the code and run as an example